# What is the use case for UserManager.isDemoUser()?

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat

This new method appeared in Android 7.1 UserManager class is described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#isDemoUser())

> Checks if the calling app is running in a demo user. When running in a demo user, apps can be more helpful to the user, or explain their features in more detail.

The use case is very unclear to me, can someone tell more? or give link to a sample?

Answer (score 1):

Via: https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#carrier-apis

> Apps can now check to see if the device is running as the demo user.
>
> Apps can call the new UserManager.isDemoUser() method to see if the app is running in a demo user sandbox. This allows apps to customize the starting experience to a potential customer. For example, when running as a demo user, an app might provide more assistance to the user, or explain its features in more detail.

One scenario would be where your app is pre-installed on an in-store demo device (ie. seeing the latest phones at a Verizon store, an app can skip the login/setup screens to give a quick demo).

Comment: How do you enter this mode?

Comment: Settings -> Developer Options -> Demo Mode

Comment: I don't think this is the same thing. It just sets the status bar in a static, empty state, of full battery, full reception and no notifications...